# Url redirection subdirectory to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using php. and i want to redirect subdirectory to subdomain and subdirectory of subdirectory to subdomain directory.

For example : if i have url like http://www.test.com/test1/

then it should be redirect to http://test1.test.com/

and second if i have url like this http://www.test.com/test1/test2/

then it should be redirect to http://test1.test.com/test2/

Any one have idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can do in .htaccess with something like..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.test.com/$2 [R,L]
```

Comment: you can also redirect from within php with header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
Note that you can only modify http header before any other output.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Do you have the persmissions to overwrite the `mod_rewrite` settings using a `.htaccess` file?