# htaccess domain/mobile to mobile.domain redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I created mobile page at http://www.domain.com/mobile/{additional indexes/paths} (not mobile directory, it's a codeigniter controller)

I created subdomain and i want mobile page to be accessed from it like this http://mobile.domain.com/{additional indexes/paths}

Also i wish i find one straight forward book/howto that explains best practices for .htaccess

Comment: possible duplicate of [Url redirection subdirectory to subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013357/url-redirection-subdirectory-to-subdomain)

Comment: I know that this would redirect my page

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.yourdomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/your-page/$1 [R=301,L]

But i want to preserve user on same URL http://mobile.domain.com/$

SO that user never realize that there is http://www.domain.com/mobile page.  (I repeat, /mobile is not folder, just path that has been also adjusted with .htaccess mode rewrite so that domain.com/index.php/mobile is also accessible via domain.com/mobile)

Comment: Remove the `R=301,` from inside the brackets and remove the `http://mobile.domain.com/` from the RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#map mobile.yourdomain.co.uk to /mobile folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile.yourdomain.co.uk$ 
RewriteCond $1 !^mobile/
RewriteRule (.*) mobile/$1 [L] 

#redirect yourdomain.co.uk/mobile to mobile.yourdomain.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.co.uk$ 
RewriteRule mobile/(.*) http://mobile.yourdomain.co.uk/$1 [R]
```

Comment: Here is "problem" #map mobile.yourdomain.co.uk to /mobile folder

As i said, unfortunately /mobile is not folder, it' just path sth like domain.com/index.php/mobile

and there is .htaccess that handles that in that way

Comment: @mariotanenbaum That should not matter, if it's an actual directory, of a 'virtual' one. The rewriterules applying to that path will get run the next cycle of the rewrite. RewriteRule are applied, over and over again, until no rule applies (i.e. the url no longer changes).